# Create Trigger on Parent table that creates row in Child table and assigns new Parent PK to Child as FK

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I have two tables:

```
Customer (customerID, firstName, lastName,....)

Account (accountID, currentBalance....customerID) customerID references CUSTOMER.
```

The tables have a 1:M (Customer:Account), Mandatory-Mandatory relationship.
I am trying to setup a trigger that automatically creates a child row when a parent is inserted, after researching Stack and elsewhere I have managed to create a trigger on the parent that creates a row in the child:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CMustHaveAccount
     AFTER INSERT ON CUSTOMER
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (accountID)
        SELECT SEQACCOUNTID.NEXTVAL
        FROM dual;
    END;
/
```

All my attempts to set the FK in Account as the new PK in Customer are failing, I tried a number of triggers, the most promising being:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AMustHaveCustomer
     AFTER INSERT ON CUSTOMER
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (customerID)
        SELECT :new.customerID
        FROM CUSTOMER;
    END;
/
```

This trigger throws back the error

> ORA-04091: table .CUSTOMER is mutating, trigger/function may not see
>   it

.
If I change the trigger to BEFORE, it gives error `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ACCOUNT"."ACCOUNTID")`. I am assuming because technically the insert has not been completed so the PK I am inserting into Customer does not yet exist.

I want to have a trigger(s) that inserts a value into Account, with a primary key from my sequence, when a row is created in Customer, and for the PK customerID to automatically be assigned to customerID in ACCOUNT as the foreign key.

I am just learning SQL and Databases, please excuse me if the answer is obvious.
Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key of ACCOUNT is the primary key of CUSTOMER, so this should work for you. Note the `:new` keyword, which is how to reference values in the current record and so avoid the "mutating table" error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CMustHaveAccount 
AFTER INSERT ON CUSTOMER 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (accountID, currentBalance, customerID) 
    values ( SEQACCOUNTID.NEXTVAL, 0, :NEW.customerID); 
END;
/
```

Comment: It worked, and so simple. I have been struggling for hours on end, thank you so much.